# Blueimp jQuery File Upload - limit by 3 files max

Tags: jquery, client-side, blueimp

I use Blueimp jQuery File Upload and want to limit max 3 files to be uploaded (at all). I have been reading documentation and did not find this ability (on client side, I mean). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution - **maxNumberOfFiles** option.

> This option limits the number of files that are allowed to be uploaded using this widget.
> By default, unlimited file uploads are allowed.
>
> The maxNumberOfFiles option depends on
> the getNumberOfFiles option, which is defined by the UI and AngularJS
> implementations.

```
$( '#input-field' ).fileupload( {
    multipart: true,
    maxNumberOfFiles: 3
} );
```

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#maxnumberoffiles

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery-file-upload's **limitMultiFileUploads** option. It is *undefined* by default, but you you can set it to whatever integer you want when initializing jquery-file-upload.

Example:

`$( '#input-field' ).fileupload( {
    multipart: true,
    limitMultiFileUploads: 3
} );`

More information about limitMultiFileUploads can be found in the documents [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#limitmultifileuploads).

Comment: read it "To limit the number of files uploaded with one XHR request, set the following option". I want to limit at 3 files at all, not one XHR request